# Setting UITableView and section direction/alignment to be RTL (Right to Left)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, right-to-left

I created a UITableView in swift, I know I can change the cell direction like this:

```
cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
```

But how can I do it to the section? and/or to the entire table?

Comment: I'd implement tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: for the section headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed @ReyGonzales comment and implemented the following `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var title: UILabel = UILabel()

    title.text = "SomeText"
    title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right

    return title
}
```